# Adding a Video file from library to application?

Tags: ios

I am currently working on uploading Photos and videos to my app. So far I got the photo uploading done, but when I access my library on my iPad, I can't see my videos or choose them. Anyone who knows how I can do this?

This is my code so far:

```
Class SixthViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var logUd: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var vælgFiler: UIButton!
    var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
    var PhotoArray = [UIImage]()
    @IBOutlet weak var upload: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        logUd.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        logUd.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        logUd.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

        vælgFiler.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        vælgFiler.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        vælgFiler.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

        upload.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        upload.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        upload.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func logUd(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {
        //myImageUploadRequest()
    }

    @IBAction func vælgFiler(_ sender: Any) {

        let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()

        self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
         select: { (assets: PHAsset) -> Void in

        },deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

        },cancel: {(assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

        }, finish: {(assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

            for i in 0..<assets.count{
                self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
            }
            self.convertAssetToImages()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

func convertAssetToImages() -> Void {

    if SelectedAssets.count != 0{

        for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count{

            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true

            manager.requestImage(for: SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in thumbnail = result!
            })
            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
            let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.PhotoArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)
        }
        self.myImageView.animationImages = self.PhotoArray
        self.myImageView.animationDuration = 10.0
        self.myImageView.startAnimating()
    }
    print("complete photo array \(self.PhotoArray)")
}
```

Comment: You are using `self.bs_presentImagePickerController` which obviously contains only images...let us know what library you are using where `bs_presentImagePickerController` is defined

Comment: @Ladislav i am using library BSImagePicker - https://github.com/shwetaporwal/iOS-Projects-PhotoApp

Answer (score 0):

If you would want `BSImagePicker` to be able to show videos as well as photos you will have to change the source of the library.

There is a file called `PhotosViewController` that displays the grid of photos. Inside is `initializePhotosDataSource` method that filters out all videos and displays only photos with:

```
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
```

if you were to delete this predicate from `fetchOptions` the library will (and I have tested this) show videos along with photos...